# Why can I only check for "number" in postman tests, but for "integer" when testing against a schema?

Tags: json, postman, schema

I am trying to figure out, why I can't seem to write a test like

```
pm.expect(responseBody.id).to.be.an("integer");
```

but apparently have to use "number".
The test fails with the message:

> AssertionError: expected 12345 to be an integer
> I am sure that it is an integer, though. I've also tried it with other responses.

When I test the response against a schema, where the id is of type "integer", it works.

So, do I only have the possibilty of checking for a "number" in the pm tests or does "number" in this case mean "integer"?

Unfortunately, I haven't found any helpful information on the postman website. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not limited to using *just* the ChaiJS getters/data-types in the tests to check for an Integer.

I don't know what your response body looks like but I've mocked this test to show how you could use [isInteger](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger) in the expect statement. This returns a `true/false` so can be asserted against like this:

```js
let test = { "number": 1234 };

pm.test("Check is an Int - 'With isInteger'", function () {
    pm.expect(Number.isInteger(test.number), `Value: ${test.number} is a ${typeof test.number} and not a number`).to.be.true;
});

pm.test("Check is an Int - 'With a number'", function () {
    pm.expect(test.number).to.be.a("number");
});
```

Comment: The above solution works, if the number is indeed an integer. Unfortunately, if it is not (I have mocked the response with a mock server), the tests fails with a rather unspecific message, because it is trying to call isInteger on e.g. a string.

Comment: The first solution is to maybe wrap the test into an if statement  to check whether the object is a number, first. Is there a more elegent solution?

Comment: If it's not a number and the test is checking for one, it's doing what it's designed to do :D - The `pm.expect()` statement takes an additional argument where you could add a custom message. I've updated the answer.